# Law of sines for tetrahedra

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Higher_dimensions) gives a generalization of the law of sines to higher dimensions, as defined in [F. Eriksson, *The law of sines for tetrahedra and n-simplices*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00181352). However, this generalization misses an important point about the standard law of sines, which relates it to the radius of the circumcircle of the triangle.

Is there a property which generalizes this relation of the 2-dimensional law of sines? In other words: is there a constant relation of this kind that all tetrahedra inscribed in a sphere of the same radius have in common?

Comment: Eriksson cites https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/CarlBAllendoerfer.pdf (generalizations of theorems about triangles, by C.B. Allendoerfer) where an elementary exposition of the law of sines for tetrahedra can be found. The following article https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691141 (On the Measure of Solid Angles, by  F. Eriksson) is also worth to see.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. See [S. Yang's 2004 paper The generalized sine law and some inequalities for simplices.](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/106_03_JIPAM/106_03.pdf)